# How to modify code to work with IE <= 9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following code which works fine in Chrome and IE 10 and FF but does not work in IE 8 and most likely in IE 9 as well:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    console.dir($j("#Button1"));
    $j("#Button1").click(function () {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
        if (textbox.length > 0) {
            //alert("Search query is not empty and redirecting...");
            window.location.href = "http://www.mypagep.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
        }
        else {
            alert("Search query is empty");
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").focus();
        }
    });
    $j('#TextBox1').keyup(function () {
        var $th = $j(this);
        $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ''));
    });
    $j('#TextBox1').keypress(function (e) {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            if (textbox.length > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = "http://www.mypage.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
            }
            else {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Search query is empty");
                document.getElementById("TextBox1").focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am using the following for the library link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I am using a CMS which seems to conflict with JQuery and that's why I am forced to use the line: `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` and use `$j` instead of the plain `$` symbol

Functionality:
If the user enters any non valid characters in the textbox the characters will be deleted. If the user presses enter in the textbox and there are characters there the user will be directed to the search page otherwise they will be displayed with an alert box. Same thing for the Search button, if the user presses but no text is in the textbox the user will be displayed with an alert box and nothing will happen, but if there is texts inside the textbox the user will be directed to the search page.

We are forced to use IE8 because some other softwares so I am trying to get it to work in older version of IE :/

How do I modify the code so it works with IE browser version that are not up to date?

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById` when using jQuery? `$('..')` does this..

Comment: What doesn't work? In IE's warning box, what line is the error? (small yellow warning sign in bottom left corner in IE8)

Comment: Firstly, you need to tell us *what* it is about the code that doesn't work. Secondly, you've got `$(document).ready()`, but then inside there you're doing `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`. If you have a jQuery conflict, then `$(document).ready()` probably won't work anyway so you need to rethink that. Why do you need `noConflict` anyway? Maybe that's relevant; tell us about  what you're doing here. Finally, what jQuery version are you using? Remember that jQuery 2.0 won't work in IE8.

Comment: I updated my question to answer the questions raised by my original question. Unfortunately there is no warning sign in the status bar :/

Comment: comment out any `console.` code firstly. This will only work in older version of IE when you have the developer tools opened up.

Comment: Building off of the `console` comment, even with the dev tools open, [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir) doesn't exist in IE8. Try changing this to a `console.log` call, or better yet just remove it.

Comment: WOW... Thanks guys! that was the issue! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir) does not exist in IE8, even with the developer tools open (the `console` object doesn't exist in < IE9 when dev tools are closed). Change this to `console.log`, or remove it. For IE8 code, you probably want to keep `console` calls out of it unless you need them for that particular moment, due to needing the dev tools open for it.

Additionally, you should strongly consider Spudley's comment about your placement of your call to `jQuery.noConflict()`. This should go *above* the `$(document).ready` call, and change it to `$j(document).ready` so that your `.ready()` call is using the no conflict jQuery variable.